# If an object has a constant force being applied to it perpendicular to gravity, will the object fall slower?

Tags: forces, gravity, propulsion

If this was on a hypothetical flat plane (so not curved like the earth) and a rocket is flying horizontally, would the horizontal propulsion slow down the rocket's descent or even stop it from falling altogether whilst it has the constant horizontal propulsion?

Comment: This is the drop a bullet shoot a bullet horizontally problem. Like the top answer says, x motion is independent of y motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force applied on the object due to propulsion and the acceleration due to gravity will create a resultant vector which is acting almost towards the direction of the rocket.

Well, no doubt there will be a descent in the rocket if the propulsion is applied in the horizontal direction. because there is no component in the rocket that can provide the lift.

The descent will be there only if there is air resistance or the rocket velocity is less than the ESCAPE VELOCITY of the hypothetical flat land.

If the rocket has managed to attain velocity greater than the escape velocity then there is no effect of the force of the gravity on the rocket causing descent or change of direction in the path of the rocket, provided there is not wind resistance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless drag force is present, the motion of the x-component of the projectile is independent of the motion in y-direction.

Comment: I understand that the x motion would not effect y motion, but my friend thinks that if it has a constant force acting on it horizontally that could effect the resultant force downward.

Comment: Actually don't worry they changed their mind.